# ip acls and DOS

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

At my company, we have been getting a lot of DOS traffic from brazil and other places lately.  My question is, I know you can deny ip ACLs at the cloud layer, but how far do those blocks go up the MS network stack?  Do they go out to very edges/roots of the Azure network so that traffic is not even switched inside to inner azure?  Are you still billed for implicit or explicit blocked traffic?  Would that traffic count against some throttle limit per customer?  What is the max traffic limit per customer before they start dropping packets?  tia

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault, not StackOverflow, since it's not a programming question.

Comment: If you're seeing these sorts of issues you should open a support ticket with Microsoft to get them to investigate. If you block IPs you will still get inbound requests which have zero cost to you and send much smaller responses than if the traffic made it to your hosts and returned markup / data.